# SO Javascript is broken? Can't comment/vote/etc

Tags: support

Suddenly and without warning, I couldn't comment/vote/etc. Chrome gives me a 403 (Forbidden) when trying to get this script: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=ff83b86e68d3 which leads to `Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined` all over the javascript.

I went to that page directly, and I see:

> Error 1000
>
> Ray ID: 12f263dfd0ce067f
>
> DNS points to prohibited IP
>
> What happened?
>
> You've requested a page on a website (cdn.sstatic.net) that is on the
>   CloudFlare network. Unfortunately, it is resolving to an IP address
>   that is creating a conflict within CloudFlare's system.
>
> What can I do?
>
> If you are the owner of this website: you should login to CloudFlare
>   and change the DNS A records for cdn.sstatic.net to resolve to a
>   different IP address.
>
> CloudFlare Ray ID: 12f263dfd0ce067f • Your IP:
>   *removed* • Help • Performance & security by CloudFlare

### FIXED

Issue is now resolved (at least, for me). Appears waiting is the solution as @AndrewMedico suggests in the comments. Thanks, too, @Oded for tracking it down.

Comment: Do you have that record marked with CloudFlare's proxy in your DNS settings (orange cloud)? That record may need to go direct by changing the cloud from orange to grey).

Comment: I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @damoncloudflare I unfortunately have no control over the DNS here. Others are experiencing the same error, so I have a feeling it's on Stack Exchange's side?

Comment: The CDN might be acting up.

Comment: Same thing happened to me a couple days ago.

Comment: @AndrewMedico what happened? Did the problem just go away after a while?

Comment: Yes, it went back to normal after an hour or so.

Comment: Problem just went away for me, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>That error is on your end.</strike>

The site that hosts our JavaScript (and other static content), cdn.sstatic.net is blocked on your end of the network.

You will need to contact your system administrators/ISP to resolve the issue.

---

<strike>We are looking into things. Might be an issue at the CDN side.</strike>

---

The story goes thus:

An inadvertent change caused an error page to get cached on a specific edge node instead of the correct JavaScript file.

We have purged the CDN cache and all should be back to normal now.

Comment: that seems odd, because I can visit the root (http://cdn.sstatic.net/) with no problem.

Comment: @pennstatephil - could be that they block only `.js` files from that domain? Perhaps you have an ad-blocker or other similar extension that does this?

Comment: I tried disabling AdBlock Plus on chrome, no change. Another hint: I can get to http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js with no problem. It seems the `?v=...` is causing my error.

Comment: @pennstatephil - apart from being a valid URL, that's just a cache breaker to ensure people have the latest version of the file. If **that** is blocked... that's really weird.

Comment: @oded: I'm getting number boxes for my inboxes, instead of the usual symbols.  Clicking on them does nothing.  Everything else seems to work, including this comment.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Working now.  They're still numbers instead of symbols, but you guys may have changed that intentionally.

Comment: Getting symbols now on Programmers, but clicking does not work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - we've not deployed in the last 16 hours, so not sure what's going on there.

Comment: I got a number box instead of the inbox symbol when you commented.  Clicking still works here, but not on programmers (refreshed several times).

Comment: Makes me wonder if the CDN is acting up

Comment: When I click on the inbox on Programmers the URL in the browser changes to `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/#`

Comment: It's that specific version string that is causing problems. Changing the last digit allows it to work no problem!

Comment: @Rob - could mean that a cached version of the file has been corrupted somewhere.

Comment: I've tried hard-clearing the cache on chrome, no help. Unless you mean on the server.

Comment: @pennstatephil - either on the CDN end or in between

Comment: this is server-side. NOT client side. appears to be a Cloudfront or Stackoverflow issue.

Comment: @tedder42 - You probably mean cloudflare.

Comment: ha @Oded- indeed. cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudflare. Too many of them!

Comment: also: working now.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly looks like a server-side issue. This is what I get when I point my browser at the url:

[image: Error Page]

If I change any part of the version string, it works just fine. That would make for an easy fix.

Comment: yep, that's the same. I just have a text version in the question.

Comment: Can I ask both you and @pennstatephil what ISP you are using?

Comment: Right now I am on client site and they appear to have their own ISP (at least according to speedtest.net/whoismyisp.org). My guess is that they are being hosted by either CenturyLink or Comcast.

Comment: @pennstatephil - thanks. Trying to figure out a common link and it might just be Comcast.

Comment: Mine says "Off Campus Telecommunications", but there's a good chance they are being hosted by either CenturyLink or Comcast as well.

Comment: @Oded bring on the merger with Time Warner Cable ;) /s