# Attempt to show comments doesn't work

Tags: bug

I don't know whether this bug is "reproducible" or "transient", but at time time I'm writing this, if you go to [Workaround for inability to have multiple inheritance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833127/workaround-for-inability-to-have-multiple-inheritance-in-java) and click on `add / show 3 comments`, it fails.

Comment: possibly related - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255942/so-javascript-is-broken-cant-comment-vote-etc

Comment: @bluefeet yes, it looks like the same thing.