# Editing Favorite Tags broken in Safari

Tags: bug

I’m not able to edit my favorite tags in Safari 8.0.7.

No errors show up in the console. I’m not using any third-party extension, so the problem must be somewhere else.

The button is working fine in Firefox.

[SO Javascript is broken? Can't comment/vote/etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255942/so-javascript-is-broken-cant-comment-vote-etc) is a similar problem, but since I can vote and comment the problem may be somewhere else (or the cached needs to get cleaned again?)